# Unmarshal innerxml to a string pointer

Tags: xml, go

Should I be able to define a struct that contains a *string and uses this to unmarshal innerxml content.

See here for an example https://play.golang.org/p/oaGu0rKYNgi

I expect the Struct variable, Containment, to point to

```
<top xmlns="http://example.com/schema/1.2/config"/>
```

Instead it is nil.

I see similar example structs in src/encoding/xml/marshal_test.go

```
type IndirInnerXML struct {
    T1       T1
    InnerXML *string `xml:",innerxml"`
    T2       T2
}
```

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The test you quoted is for `Marshal`, not for `Unmarshal`. There is no test for `*string` for innerxml for Unmarshal; there is one to prove that it won't work with `[]string`, and that it will work with `[]byte` and `string`, but that's it. According to [the docs for `Unmarshal`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/xml/#Unmarshal):

> If the struct has a field of type `[]byte` or `string` with tag `",innerxml"`, Unmarshal accumulates the raw XML nested inside the element in that field. The rest of the rules still apply.

It supports `[]byte` and `string` *exclusively* for unmarshalling inner XML. 
Whether `*string` *should* be supported is a question for the Go maintainers.

Comment: Thanks @Adrian yes this was my understanding, looking to get a view on whether others believe this is a valid use case before approaching the authors.  I need to support both empty and not set semantics, from reading online I see a lot of people using pointers in unmarshaling structs to represent not set, referring to go protobuf as an example of this.

Comment: Hard to make that case, XML's innerxml can be empty but the concept of "not set" doesn't really apply to innertext/innerxml. It makes sense for attributes or children with can be missing, present but empty, it present but filled, but plain contents are just empty or filled.